# Safari: AudioContext MediaElementAudioSourceNode does not respect playbackRate

Tags: audio, safari, mediaelement, audiocontext, webkitaudiocontext

I'm currently working on an application that uses the AudioContext api to control audio for both video clips and background audio. We would like to use the AudioContext (and therefore `MediaElementAudioSourceNodes`) so we can make adjustments to the audio programmatically.

Because the application is syncing up media to a timeline, this often means adjusting the `playbackRate` of the media element to catch up. In Chrome, this works fine: you adjust `playbackRate` and the media speeds up or slows down accordingly. Now in Safari, any audio piped through a `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` will not respect the changed media `playbackRate`, playing the audio at normal speed and will then sputter out after a few seconds. (Safari audio *will* respect the `playbackRate` when played directly from the media element, notably without pitch correction, but that is a separate, known, issue)

[Here's a CodeSandbox that replicates the issue.](https://codesandbox.io/s/safari-mediaelementsource-playbackrate-snekl) The first player on the page will play audio back coming directly from the `HTMLMediaElement`, where as the second player will pipe it through a `MediaElementAudioSourceNode`.

We've tried a couple other avenues, such as using an `AudioBufferSourceNode` for the audio source, but due to the size of clip we're often working with, this is not a desired avenue. If at all possible, we would like to still use the `AudioContext` api for both Chrome and Safari as well.